# not able to render response in firefox

Tags: html, firefox

Hi I'm trying to render below html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body >
    <select id="countrySelect" size="1">
        <option></option>
        <option>USA</option>
        <option>Singapore</option>
    </select>
    <button >show selected</button>
</body>
</html>
```

But getting following error in browser console:
**The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.**

Comment: What exactly is the challenge?

Comment: Its returning blank html page whatever i put on server, and above error is shown in browser console.

Comment: What is it supposed to return?

Comment: the html page, but if i view the source its blank.

Comment: Even the dropdown doesn't work?What version are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below Html code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <title>Untitled Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <select id="countrySelect" size="1">
          <option></option>
          <option>USA</option>
          <option>Singapore</option>
        </select>
        <button>show selected</button>
      </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Same result, no success.